# Itune Connect Web Scraping, Powershell, can not logging in - what is “the AuxValue”?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, app-store-connect

I have been trying this project since the end of the last year, and I am stuck with this problem for a long time. I really need a help please.

The problem is I think I am not logging in

my code is

```
    $loginBase = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com";
$loginUrl = $loginBase + "/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo";

$r = Invoke-WebRequest $loginUrl -SessionVariable ws;

$ws

$form = $r.Forms[0];

$form| Format-List


$form.fields

$form.Fields["accountname"] = "username";
$form.Fields["accountpassword"]  = "password";
$form.Fields["theAuxValue"]  = "";

$form.fields

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ($loginBase + $form.Action) -WebSession $ws -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields;

$r.StatusCode
$r.StatusDescription
$r.content




$jsonSummaryUrl = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/ra/apps/manageyourapps/summary";

$response = Invoke-WebRequest $jsonSummaryUrl -WebSession $ws;

$response.StatusCode
$response.StatusDescription
$response.content
```

The output is

```
Headers               : {}
Cookies               : System.Net.CookieContainer
UseDefaultCredentials : False
Credentials           : 
Certificates          : 
UserAgent             : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/3.0
Proxy                 : 
MaximumRedirection    : -1





Id     : appleConnectForm
Method : post
Action : /WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/0.0.1.17.3.13.3.2.1.1.3.1.1
Fields : {[accountname, ], [accountpassword, ], [theAuxValue, ], [inframe, 0]}




Key                                                                                                               Value                                                                                                            
---                                                                                                               -----                                                                                                            
accountname                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
accountpassword                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
theAuxValue                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
inframe                                                                                                           0                                                                                                                
accountname                                                                                                       username                                                                                                         
accountpassword                                                                                                   password                                                                                                         
theAuxValue                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
inframe                                                                                                           0                                                                                                                
200
OK

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>iTunes Connect</title>     
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=376771144" />
    <link href="/c/1450307132/dcfcd616d3232d45ba91c598fceecb45/itc/css/compiled/global_header_footer.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/c/1450307132/b5be5ab894bfb31372e451d4ef495483/itc/css/compiled/interstitial.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/c/1450307132/32843bda7b7abb11a2ca7d7a1088c6f3/itc/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="signin"><div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">


              <span>iTunes Connect</span>

          </div>
          <a href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/sellcontent/" class="hero-link hl--secondary">Learn More</a>

              <div id="resources-help" class="dropdownmenu">
                <a href="" class="icon-help menuopener"></a>
                <ul role="menu" id="help-menu">
                    <li class="sectionBreak"><a href="https://itunesconnect.apple.com/help/">All Resources and Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://itunesconnect.apple.com/help/news/">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://itunesconnect.apple.com/help/guides/">Guides</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://itunesconnect.apple.com/help/videos/">Videos</a></li>
                    <li class="sectionBreak"><a href="https://itunesconnect.apple.com/help/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>


    </div>







          <script>
          window.l10login = {
            signIn:   'Sign In',
            appleID:  'Apple ID',
            password: 'Password',
            signedOut: 'You have successfully signed out.',
            sessionExpired: 'Your session has expired.',
          }
          </script>

            <div id="wrapper" class="itc-auth">


                <div class="box-container">

                    <div class="box sign-in">
                        <h2 class="itc-signin-header">
                            Sign In to</br> iTunes Connect
                        </h2>
                        <script>
    function dsfocus(){ document.appleConnectForm.theAccountName.focus(); }
</script>



        <div id="ds_container">








            <form name="appleConnectForm" method="post" action="/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/1.0.1.17.3.13.3.2.1.1.3.1.1">






                    <font face="Lucida Grande, Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" class="L12" />
                    <font size=2>
                        <span class="dstext"></span>
                    </font>
                    </font /><br><br>



                    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                        <tr valign='top'>
                            <td><img alt="Alert" width="16" height="11" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/iconsmallalert.gif" />
                                <font face="Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size=1 class="G10" /><font color="#ff0000" size=1>
                                    <span class="dserror">Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly.</span>
                                </font></font />
                                <br><br>
                            </td>
                            <td width='11'></td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>





                    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=273>
                        <tr valign=top>
                            <td align=left><font size=2><font face="Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size=1 class="G10" />
                                <label for="accountname"><span class="dslabel">Apple ID</span></label>
                                <font color="#ff1102"></font></font /><br>
                                <font size='2'><input size="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="128" id="accountname" type="text" name="theAccountName" /></font></font>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr><td><img alt="" width="273" height="5" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/spacer.gif" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><img alt="" width="273" height="5" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/spacer.gif" /></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align='left'>
                                <font face="Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size=1 class="G10" />
                                    <label for="accountpassword"><span class="dslabel">Password</span></label>
                                </font />
                                <br>
                                <input size="30" autocapitalize="off" oncut="return false ;" oncopy="return false ;" autocorrect="off" id="accountpassword" type="password" name="theAccountPW" /><input border="0" width="0" height="0" type="image" name=
"1.Continue" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/spacer.gif" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                        <tr><td><img alt="" width="273" height="5" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/spacer.gif" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><img alt="" width="273" height="5" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/spacer.gif" /></td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='273' cellpadding='0'>
                                    <tr align='left'>

                                            <td align='left' width='170'>



                                                    <font size='1'>
                                                        <span class="dstext">






                                                                    <input border="0" alt="Did you forget your password?" type="image" name="1.Forgot" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/labelconnect/iforgot-link.png" />


                                                        </span>
                                                    </font>

                                            </td>
                                            <td width='15'><img alt="" width="15" height="5" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/spacer.gif" /></td>



                                            <td align='left' width='88'><input border="0" alt="Sign In" type="image" name="1.Continue" src="/AppleConnect/US-EN/labelconnect/btn-sign-in.png" /></td>


                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="theAuxValue" />
                    <input id="inframe" type="hidden" value="0" name="inframe" />

            </form>








    <script>
        var isInIframe = (self != top);
        var elem = document.getElementById("inframe");
        if (isInIframe==false)
            elem.value="0";
        else
            elem.value="1";
    </script>
</div>










                        <input style='display: none' id="ac_invites" type="text" name="0.1.17.3.13.5" />
                        <div id="msg-container">



                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="box-signin-shadow"></div>

                  </div>




            </div>


        <div class="modal-container" style="display: none">
        <form method="post" class="dsform" action="" id="expiredPasswordFormClone">
            <div id="modal" class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog-content">

                      <h1>Password Expired</h1>
                      <p style="margin-top: 10px">Your password has expired. To change it, go to <a href="http://appleid.apple.com">appleid.apple.com</a>.</p>




                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-buttons">
                    <div class="right-buttons">
                      <button class="primary" onclick="cancelExpiredForm()">Close</button>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
        </div>




    <script>
    (function() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.setAttribute('class', 'signin');
    })();
    </script>
    <script>

   $(function() {
        // Add Learn More link to header.
        // var learnMoreText = 'Learn More',
        //    learnMoreLink = '<a href="http://www.apple.com/itunes/sellcontent/" class="hero-link hl--secondary">'+learnMoreText+'</a>';
        //$('#header').append(learnMoreLink);

       // Add iForgot link to footer
       var iForgotLink = "<li><a href='https://iforgot.apple.com/password'>Forgot your Apple ID or password?</a></li>";
       $(iForgotLink).insertBefore('#footer li:first-child')

       // If we receive "Expired Password" interface, display it as a modal window
        var expForm = $('form[name="appleConnectExpiredPasswordForm"]');
        if ( expForm.length > 0 ) {

            var errors = expForm.find('span.dserror');
            var action = expForm.attr('action');

            if (errors.length > 0) {
                errors.each( function() {
                    $('#ds_error_list').append('<li><div class="errormessages">'+$(this).text()+'</div></li>' );
                    $('#ds_error_list').show();
                })
            } else {
              $('#ds_error_list').hide();
            }

            var newForm = expForm.clone();

            $('.box.sign-in').hide();
            $('#expiredPasswordFormClone').attr('name','appleConnectExpiredPasswordForm').attr('action',action);
            $('.modal-container').show();
            expForm.remove();
        }



   });
      window.submitExpiredForm = function() {
        var form = document.appleConnectExpiredPasswordForm || document.getElementById('expiredPasswordFormClone') || document.forms[0];
        if (typeof form.submit === 'function') {
          form.submit();
        }
        return form;
      }

        var cancelExpiredForm = function() {
          document.cookie="wosid=''; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";
          /* $('.box.sign-in').show();
          $('.modal-container').hide();*/
        }
    </script>



</div>


<div id="footer" class="footer not-global-style">
    <a href="http://www.apple.com" class="no-text ico-apple">Apple.com</a>
    <div class="right">
        <p>
            Copyright &copy; 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.apple.com/legal/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- <script src="/c/1450307132/c73408c8ecc03f63c15cd8ff11536d1d/itc/js/cleanwrapper.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/c/1450307132/e15e739d0caf0edc86dd4889060ae763/itc/js/signin.js"></script>
</body>
</HTML>



<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/c/1450307132/ef79b24de870765686c7bce9b178a66a/itc/js/omniture/library.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
/* You may give each page an identifying name, server, and channel on
the next lines. */
s.pageName="iTC Sign In Redesign"
s.channel="Sign In"


s.hier5="appleitmsitcdev"


/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
//--></script><noscript><img src="http://metrics.apple.com/b/ss/appleitmsna/1/H.24--NS/0"
height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" /></noscript>





200
OK
```

**I did not post the output of $response.content since Stackoverflow allows me less than 30000 character and the output is exact same with $r.content**

What really confuses me is that I changed the Username and Password for this post and run the script, the output was exactly the same one when I put my real password and username, and I executed. I noticed that I am not logging in.

so, I wonder that I have to fill theAuxvalue, this is just my guess.

If someone who had similar experience, please let me know.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had some issues connecting to iTunes Connect with Web Scraping.
Turns out, Apple has updated the iTunes connect around the month of Novembre 2015.
Where before you needed to pass the following paramaters : 
***theAccountName***
***theAccountPW***

You now need to pass the following parameters : 
***accountName***
***password***
***rememberMe***

Where ***rememberMe*** is a boolean (true or false).

But **that's not all**, url's have changed too (login, data endpoints) and cookie policy.
This is how you should proceed : 
With **BASE URL** being : https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa

1. Step 1 : Do your login request on https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin with the three parameters **encoded as json**
2. Step 2 : If all is well, you should have a cookie named ***myacinfo*** with the response
3. Step 3 : You now have to do a request on URL **BASE_URL/route?noext** to retreive two other cookies you will need for your session : ***wosid*** and ***woinst***
4. Step 4 : Nearly done... You now need to do one last request on the following URL **BASE_URL** in order to retreive the cookie named ***itctx***. Present you previously retreived ***wosid***,***woinst*** and ***myacinfo*** for this request.
5. Step 5 : You now have all the necessary Cookies for your current session and can start fetching some data :). For example, call **BASE_URL/ra/apps/manageyourapps/summary/v2** to fetch the summary for all apps.

   Here is a quick and dirty working example (as of 27th Jan 2016) in PHP which might help you (sorry it isn't commented, it's just a POC):

   ```
   class itunesConnectApi
   {
   private $_baseURL               = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/";
   private $_itunesUserLoginKey    = "accountName";
   private $_itunesUserLoginPass   = "password";
   private $_itunesUserRemember    = "rememberMe";
   private $_currentCookies        = null;
   private $_cookiesToUse          = array();
   private $_loginURL              = "https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin";



   public function login($user,$password) {

       //Execute the cURL
       $response = $this->executeCurl($this->_loginURL,false,"POST",array( $this->_itunesUserLoginKey=>$user,
                                                                           $this->_itunesUserLoginPass=>$password,
                                                                           $this->_itunesUserRemember=>true));

       //Do we have the myacinfo cookie ?
       if(isset($this->_currentCookies["myacinfo"])){

           //Add it to current cookies we should use
           $this->_cookiesToUse["myacinfo"] = $this->_currentCookies["myacinfo"];          
           return true;
       }
       return false;

   }

   public function loginOverHead()
   {

       $url         = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/route?noext";
       $response    = $this->executeCurl($url,false,"GET");

       if(isset($this->_currentCookies["wosid"]) && isset($this->_currentCookies["woinst"])){

           $this->_cookiesToUse["wosid"] = $this->_currentCookies["wosid"];
           $this->_cookiesToUse["woinst"] = $this->_currentCookies["woinst"];

           return $this->getItcTx();
       }
       return false;

   }

   public function getItcTx()
   {
       $url         = "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa";
       $response    = $this->executeCurl($url,false,"GET");

       if(isset($this->_currentCookies["itctx"])){
           $this->_cookiesToUse["itctx"] = $this->_currentCookies["itctx"];
           return true;
       }
       return false;

   }


   public function fetchData($url)
   {
       $data = $this->executeCurl($url,false);     
       header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
       print_r($data["data"]);
       die;
   }

   private function executeCurl($url,$follow_redirect = true,$httpMethod = "GET",$data = array())
   {
       $fields_string = "";

       if(count($data) > 0){
           foreach($data as $key=>$value) { 
               $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
           }
           $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

           if($httpMethod == "GET"){
               $url = $url."?".$fields_string;
           }
       }       

       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);  
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
               'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                       
       );

       if($httpMethod == "POST" && count($data) > 0){
           curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");   
           curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
           curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
       }        

       if($this->_currentCookies != null){         
           if(isset($this->_currentCookies["wosid"]) && isset($this->_currentCookies["woinst"]))
           {               
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);                
               $cookie = "";
               foreach($this->_cookiesToUse as $key=>$val){
                   $cookie.= $key."=".$val.";";
               }
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie); 

           }
           else if(isset($this->_currentCookies["myacinfo"])){

               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

               $cookie = "";
               foreach($this->_currentCookies as $key=>$val){
                   $cookie.= $key."=".$val.";";
               }
               curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);            
           }
       }


       $return = curl_exec($curl);
       $info   = curl_getinfo($curl);
       $code   = $info["http_code"];
       curl_close($curl);

       $this->extractCookies($return);

       if($code == 302 ){

           if($follow_redirect){
               return $this->executeCurl($info["redirect_url"]);
           }else{

               if($this->_currentCookies == null){
                   $this->extractCookies($return);
               }
               return true;
           }       
       }

       $header_size= $info["header_size"];
       $header     = substr($return, 0, $header_size);
       $body       = substr($return, $header_size);
       return array("info"=>$info,"data"=>$body);      
   }

   private function extractCookies($result)
   {   
       preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
       $cookies = array();
       foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
           parse_str($item, $cookie);
           $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
       }
       $this->_currentCookies = $cookies;
    }
   }
   ```

And then you just use it like so :

```
define('ITUNES_CONNECT_LIST_APPS','https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/manageyourapps/summary/v2');
$api    = new itunesConnectApi();
if($l   = $api->login("myappleid@login.fr","myextremepassword")){
    
    if($api->loginOverHead()){
        $allAppData = $api->fetchData(ITUNES_CONNECT_LIST_APPS);
        
        print_r("<pre>");
        print_r($allAppData);
        print_r("</pre>");
        
    }else{
    
        die("unable to fetch additionnal cookies");
    
    }
}else{
    
    die("unable to login");
    
}
die;
```

You can also have a look at fastlane spaceship, they do the same in their tunes_client.rb file.
Hope this will help you :)